# Python rounding does not work because of scientific number

Tags: python

Very simple, I want to round my 'base_price' and 'entry' with the precision, here 0.00001. It doesn't work because it converts it to a scientific number.
How do I do this; I have been stuck for 1 hour.

Some post says to use `output="{:.9f}".format(num)` but it adds some zero after the last 1.

It work with `precision = str(0.0001)` but start from 4 zeros after the dot, it change to scientific numbers and `digit = precision[::-1].find('.')` doesn't work with scientific numbers.

```
precision = str(0.00001) #5 decimals after the dot
print(precision)
base_price=0.0314858333
entry=0.031525

digit = precision[::-1].find('.')
entry_price = float(round(float(entry), digit))
base_price = float(round(float(base_price), digit))
print(entry_price,base_price)
```

Expected result:

```
base_price=0.03148 #5 decimals after the dot
entry=0.03152 #5 decimals after the dot
```

Comment: Why are you going through all that stuff with `str(0.00001)` and `find`? Why not just use `digit=5`?

Comment: Python uses the hardware's double - a binary float, not a decimal float. The decimal numbers you write are just estimates of the binary number actually used. That's normally okay. But it can play havoc with financial calculations. The `decimal` module does decimal math and lets you set a precision. This is a long winded way of asking you what you want the precision for ... is it just display? Is it needed for your calculations?

Comment: It for precision price, the expected result is base_price=0.03148
entry=0.03152 so 5 decimals after the dot same as the precision price. Needed for calculation

Comment: If its just display, `output="{:.5f}".format(entry_price)` should do.

Comment: I have hundreds of it with different price precision

Comment: based on some comments you made on some answers, I'd recommend you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use numbers in the format '0.00001' to set precision instead of the number you want, I'd use int(abs(math.log10(precision))) then pass that number to format.

Like so

```py
import math
precision = 0.00001
precision_count = int(abs(math.log10(precision)))

base = 0.0314858333
entry = 0.031525

print(f"{entry:.{precision_count}f}, {base:.{precision_count}f}")
```

*(I've removed suffix `_price` from `base_price` because in one case you used `entry` and `entry_price` and in the other you used `base_price` twice, so I went with the first standard for both)*

**I'd recommend you test with multiple possible values of precision**

#### But, you *probably* should be using [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead

Based on the variable names having "price", you could run into rounding problems/error compounding. To avoid surprises, I recommend you use decimal (or something with similar capabilities). In your case, `quantize` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: with base = 0.0314958333 , it gives 0.03150 It should be 0.03149

Comment: Then I recommend quantize with ROUND_DOWN in your decimal's context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round to a precision given by a variable, you can just do

```py
precision = 0.00001
entry = 0.031525
entry_price = round(entry / precision) * precision
```

Comment: it gives me 0.031525 and 0.0314858333 . Instead of base_price=0.03148
entry=0.03152

Comment: @Oneboy what have you done? In my Python 3.10.7, `entry=0.031525;precision = 0.00001;print(round(entry / precision) * precision)` gives `0.03152`. The other is right to floating-point precision as well.

Comment: try with entry = 0.031526 , it will gives you 0.03153 / I expect 0.03152

Comment: @Oneboy If you want to always round down, replace `round` with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to truncate the number, so:

```
precision = 0.00001
base_price = 0.0314858333

# use int to truncate the division to the nearest fraction. 
base_price = int(base_price / precision) * precision 
print(base_price) # prints 0.03148
```

Comment: What hardware are you running this on? 
When I run it on my Dell Latitude 9430 laptop, it shows 0.03148

Comment: Can you try with base_price = 0.0314958333 it gives me 0.031490000000000004

Comment: This sounds like you're more concerned with how it prints than the accuracy of the calculation, as that 2nd number is extremely close to what you want (0.03149). These numbers are all getting converted to binary floats and back to decimal for display. Binary (base-2) runs into rounding problems just like decimal and can have small errors when converting back and forth. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate, as a user commented in the original question.

Comment: Extremely close is not enough in trading. thanks for the link. I'm reading it

Comment: Then perhaps using the Decimal library, as another user pointed out. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html